# how to connect sqlite3 with electron js

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron, node-sqlite3

please guide me through a full process, that I connect my electron app with sqlite3.
because I have a lot of issues occurring in my electron js.
Thank you.

**Main.js:**

```
const{app,BrowserWindow,ipcMain}=require("electron");
app.on("ready",createWindow);

const si = require("systeminformation");
require("electron-reload")(__dirname);

function createWindow()
{
    const window = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height:600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
        }

    });
    window.webContents.openDevTools();
    window.loadFile(__dirname+ "/index.html");

}

ipcMain.on("get-cpu-usage",(events,args)=>{

console.log(args);
});
```

**renderer.js:**

```
const{ipcRender} = require("electron")

const os=require("os");
const cpuName=document.getElementById("cpu-name");
const cpuCores =document.getElementById("cores");
const cpuUsage =document.getElementById("cpu-usage");


const cpus=os.cpus();
cpuName.innerText=`CPU: ${cpus[0].model}`;
cpuCores,innerText=`Cores Available: ${cpus.length}`;

setInterval(() =>{
    console.log("sending message to get cpu stats")
    ipcRender.send("get-cpu-usage", "Hello sheraz The render process")
},2000)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest way to use SQLite with electron is with electron-builder.

First, add a postinstall step in your package.json:

```
"scripts": {
   "postinstall": "install-app-deps"
   ...
}
```

and then install the necessary dependencies and build:

```
npm install --save-dev electron-builder
npm install --save sqlite3
npm run postinstall
```

electron-builder will build the native module for your platform, with the correct name for the Electron binding; and you can then require it in code as normal.

Comment: when i install electron-builder then save sqlite3 at last i install postinstall it cought an error.PS C:\Users\Muhammad Sheraz\electron-quick-start> npm run postinstall
npm ERR! missing script: postinstall

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Muhammad Sheraz\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-03T15_16_19_166Z-debug.log